# Appending a list inside a function

Tags: python

I am still a bit confused about how arguments are passed in python.
I thought non-primitive types are passed by reference, but why does the following code not print [1] then?

```
def listTest(L):
    L = L + [1]


def main:
    l = []
    listTest(l)

    print l #prints []
```

and how could I make it work.
I guess I need to pass "a pointer to L" by reference

Comment: *All* types are passed in by *assignment*: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986006)

Comment: as a funny note, a list can act as a pointer: `l = [[]]`, `L[0] = L[0] + [1]`, `print l[0]`

Comment: Python doesn't distinguish between primitive and non-primitive types. Everything is an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `listTest()` you are *rebinding* `L` to a new `list` object; `L + [1]` creates a new object that you then assign to `L`. This leaves the original `list` object that `L` referenced before untouched.

You need to manipulate the `list` object referenced by `L` directly by calling methods on it, such as `list.append()`:

```
def listTest(L):
    L.append(1)
```

or you could use `list.extend()`:

```
def listTest(L):
    L.extend([1])
```

or you could use in-place assignment, which gives mutable types the opportunity to alter the object in-place:

```
def listTest(L):
    L += [1]
```

Comment: I don't like `in-place assignement` because you never know if the object is modified or re-assigned (unless you know exactly what object is passed)

Comment: @njzk2: yes, it is not suitable for mixed-type settings where you expect the original object to always be mutated.